# Compute and save the r-squared value of bootstrap objects in a new dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, nls, statistics-bootstrap

I have a dataframe `df`

```
dput(df)
    structure(list(x = c(49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 1, 2, 3, 
    4, 5, 14, 15, 16, 17, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 3, 30, 64, 66, 67, 
    68, 69, 34, 35, 37, 39, 2, 17, 18, 99, 100, 102, 103, 67, 70, 
    72), y = c(2268.14043972082, 2147.62290922552, 2269.1387550775, 
    2247.31983098201, 1903.39138268307, 2174.78291538358, 2359.51909126411, 
    2488.39004804939, 212.851575751527, 461.398994384333, 567.150629704352, 
    781.775113821961, 918.303706148872, 1107.37695799186, 1160.80594193377, 
    1412.61328924168, 1689.48879626486, 260.737164468854, 306.72700499362, 
    283.410379620422, 366.813913489692, 387.570173754128, 388.602676983443, 
    477.858510450125, 128.198042456082, 535.519377609133, 1028.8780498564, 
    1098.54431357711, 1265.26965941035, 1129.58344809909, 820.922447928053, 
    749.343583476846, 779.678206156474, 646.575242339517, 733.953282899613, 
    461.156280127354, 906.813018662913, 798.186995701282, 831.365377249207, 
    764.519073183124, 672.076289062505, 669.879217186302, 1341.47673353751, 
    1401.44881976186, 1640.27575962036)), .Names = c("x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -45L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have created two non-linear regression (nls1 and nls2) based on my dataset.

```
library(stats)
    nls1 <- nls(y~A*(x^B)*(exp(k*x)), 
                data = df, 
                start = list(A = 1000, B = 0.170, k = -0.00295))
    nls2<-nls(y~A*x^3+B*x^2+C*x+D, data=df,
        start = list(A=0.02, B=-0.6, C= 50, D=200))
```

I then computed bootstrap objects for these two functions to get multiple sets of parameters (A,B and k for nls1 and A, B, C and D for nls2).

```
library(nlstools)
Boo1 <- nlsBoot(nls1, niter = 200)
Boo2 <- nlsBoot(nls2, niter = 200)
```

Based on this bootstrap objects, I would like to compute r-squared of each combination of parameters and save the min, max and median of my r-squared values for each bootstrap object into one new dataframe. The dataframe could look like `new.df`.

```
structure(list(Median = c(NA, NA), Max = c(NA, NA), Min = c(NA, 
NA)), .Names = c("Median", "Max", "Min"), row.names = c("nls1", 
"nls2"), class = "data.frame")
```

The idea is then to do some box plots with the median, min and max values for each non-linear model based on bootstrapping to compare them. Can someone help me out with that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what r-squared are you thinking?  It's not usually a great measure of fit for non-linear models.

Comment: Well, it could also be AIC or Modelling efficiency (MEF) which is bit better.

Comment: There is `boot` from `library(boot)` where you define a function to return the statistic of interest.  `library(boot); stat <- function(dat, inds) { fit <- try(nls(y~A*(x^B)*(exp(k*x)), data = dat[inds,], start = list(A = 1000, B = 0.170, k = -0.00295)), silent=TRUE); if (inherits(fit, "nls")) AIC(fit) else NA }; res <- boot(df, stat, R=200)`.  Then you can take the quantiles of `res$t`

Comment: Right. But the idea is to create a new final dataframe which could summarize the Median, quantiles, etc. from the bootstrapping of a number  of n non-linear functions.

Comment: with the statistic function, you can put whatever you want in there.  So, you could fit as many models in a single bootstrap as you want, returning a `c(stat1, stat2, etc)` vector.  then `res$t` will be a matrix of all the estimates.  Then, it is simply extracting what you want from that (`apply` by column) into a data.frame.

Comment: Ok. Make sense. Could you please write the complete command line including the two nls function provided including both AIC and MEF values? You can then put them as an answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the `inds` object BTW?

Comment: `inds` is the random indices chosen for each iteration of the bootstrap procedure.  It's  a confusing requirement of the statistic function, but is documented in `?boot`.  As for a complete solution, it is just duplicating the fitting for two models in what i already wrote above.

Comment: I have now tried this but I could not get what I want. I am making some coding mistake I guess. `stat <- function(dat, inds) { 
{fit <- try(nls(y~A*(x^B)*(exp(k*x)), data = dat[inds,], start = list(A = 1000, B = 0.170, k = -0.00295)), silent=TRUE);  if (inherits(fit, "nls")) AIC(fit) else NA
return(stat1) 
}
{fit2 <- try(nls(y~A*x^3+B*x^2+C*x+D, data = dat1[inds1,], start = list(A=0.02, B=-0.6, C= 50, D=200)), silent=TRUE); if (inherits(fit2, "nls")) AIC(fit) else NA
return(stat2)
}
} 

res<-lapply(df, boot, statistic= stat, R=200)`.@bunk can you help me out to fix it?

Comment: ok, it would be like this, `stat <- function(dat, inds) { fit <- try(nls(y~A*(x^B)*(exp(k*x)), data = dat[inds,], start = list(A = 1000, B = 0.170, k = -0.00295)), silent=TRUE); f1 <- if (inherits(fit, "nls")) AIC(fit) else NA; fit2 <- try(nls(y~A*x^3+B*x^2+C*x+D, data = dat[inds,], start = list(A=0.02, B=-0.6, C= 50, D=200)), silent=TRUE); f2 <- if (inherits(fit2, "nls")) AIC(fit2) else NA; c(f1, f2) }; res <- boot(df, stat, R=200)`.  Then, to get medians for example, `apply(res$t, 2, median, na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks a lot. I will put it in the answer.

Comment: And if I want to add more test than AIC. I can just add them after `AIC(fit)`, right? Like `AIC(fit) test1(fit) test2(fit) else NA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from @bunk

```
stat <- function(dat, inds) { fit <- try(nls(y~A*(x^B)*(exp(k*x)), data = dat[inds,], start = list(A = 1000, B = 0.170, k = -0.00295)), silent=TRUE); f1 <- if (inherits(fit, "nls")) AIC(fit) else NA; fit2 <- try(nls(y~A*x^3+B*x^2+C*x+D, data = dat[inds,], start = list(A=0.02, B=-0.6, C= 50, D=200)), silent=TRUE); f2 <- if (inherits(fit2, "nls")) AIC(fit2) else NA; c(f1, f2) }; res <- boot(df, stat, R=200). Then, to get medians for example, apply(res$t, 2, median, na.rm=TRUE)
```